# What do "Hit:" and "Get:" mean in the output of apt-get update?

Tags: apt, updates

I'm very new to Linux. I'm trying to gain an understanding of APT and would like some clarity on the output of this command. What am I to glean from this?

`apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                              
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 306 kB in 0s (377 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

What is a hit and what is a get?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to know, you could download a copy of the source:

```
git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/apt/apt.git
```

But my sense of the status words are:

`Hit:`  Comparing metadata with remote site.

`Get:`  Fetching new, improved version from remote site.

`Ign:`  A non-critical error occurred.

`Err:`  A critical error occurred.